# Zsh output redirection behavior

Tags: bash, zsh, io-redirection

In `bash`:

```
bash% echo xxx >&2 | wc
xxx
   0   0   0
```

In `zsh`:

```
zsh% echo xxx >&2 | wc
xxx
   1   1   4
zsh% { echo xxx >&2; } | wc
xxx
   0   0   0
```

How do I make `zsh` behave like `bash` for this case? Is there a `zsh` option to set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning off the MULTIOS option changes this behavior.

```
% echo xxx >&2 | wc
xxx
       1       1       4
% setopt NOMULTIOS
% echo xxx >&2 | wc
xxx
       0       0       0
```

With the option set, a single command can have multiple IO redirections, and for this purpose, it appears the pipe counts as one.

Comment: According to http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios, with `MULTIOS` on, `echo xxx >&2 | wc` seems to echo `stdout` to **both** `stderr(2)` and `wc`

Comment: After I posted this, I did find a note in the `man zshmisc` under `MULTIOS` that pipes count as implicit redirections for standard out.

Answer (score 4):

To change the behavior **ad-hoc**, you can simply **parenthesize**:

```
(echo xxx >&2) | wc
```

Note that there is no side effect from parenthesizing here, as even without it your commands run in subshells, due to use of a pipe (`|`).

To change the behavior **for the entire shell**, see [@chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22764008/45375).

---

**Performance considerations**:

@chepner asks in a comment whether the parentheses result in an *additional* subshell (and thus child process).

The surprising answer is the opposite:
With option `MULTIOS` ON (the default), using parentheses results in *1 fewer* subshell.

With option `MULTIOS` OFF, the parentheses (which are then not needed) make no difference.

---

How I tested:

On OS X 10.9.2, I used `sudo dtruss -t fork -f -p {pidOfZsh}` to monitor `fork()` calls in a `zsh` shell; `zsh` version is `zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0)`.

With option `MULTIOS` ON, `echo xxx >&2 | wc` forked *3* times, while `(echo xxx >&2) | wc` only forked *2* times.

Comment: Does `zsh` optimize this, or does it simply start *another* subshell in the subshell created by the pipe?